# How to store object

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

How can I store Bluetooth Socket that is obtained in one activity? So I can use it in another activity to manage connection. Or is there any other way to transfer Bluetooth Socket from one activity to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cant transfer complex objects via `Bundle`, try and use a different class to store your information (the socket in this instance).